# JMapViewer Issue

Tags: java, jmapviewer

I am designing a ***JAVA program*** that retrieves coordinates of capitals from an XML File and displays MarkerDots  in the Panel Containing the map; and I need to add a mouse listener event to this map in such a way that if the user clicked the mouse button on a dot, a Menu pops out showing details about the capital. I designed all of that, ***but my problem*** is that ***i need a way to get the coordinates of the dot relative to the Panel*** not the real coordinates(on earth) in order ***to check if the user clicked on the dot or outside it***. So is there a possible way?

***Any Help is appreciated!***

Comment: Thank you for you leading me to the correct answer, but please I need some more clarification because I am a really java beginner!

Comment: That's to say I didn't understand well what to do!

Comment: How would I add a working mouse listener to the dots so that if i press on the marker dot some event occurs like Opening a JOption pane for example

Comment: I appreciate any extra help since this is for a university project